# Canvas doesnt rendering image from input

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Hi i want to draw image that is inserted in input. I get a right data in my image object and i can show img in body as html element, but my canvas doesnt rendering it.

here is my html

```
        <canvas id="loadImageCanvas"></canvas>
        <input id="loadImageInput" type="file">
```

here is my javascript

```
class ImageEditor{

constructor(){
    this.canvasElement = document.getElementById('loadImageCanvas');
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('loadImageCanvas').getContext('2d');
    this.imageInput = document.getElementById('loadImageInput');
    this.loadedImg = new Image();
   }

loadImage = () => {
    console.log(this.loadedImg)
    this.canvas.drawImage(this.loadedImg, 0, 0);
   }

init = () =>{
    this.canvasElement.width = 300;
    this.canvasElement.height = 300;
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loadImageInput").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    })
})

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
        reader.onload = function(e) {
        imgEditor.loadedImg.src = e.target.result;
        imgEditor.canvas.drawImage(imgEditor.loadedImg, 0, 0);
        imgEditor.loadImage();
        }
    }
  }

let imgEditor = new ImageEditor();
imgEditor.init();
```

In fact i was able to render image on canvas when i used two same event listeners for my input, but i dont understant why it doesnt work with one event listener.

Comment: Was your canvas loaded before the JS or rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix following part. Image drawing should be in image's onload callback.

```
  loadImage = () => {
    console.log(this.loadedImg)
    this.loadedImg.onload = () => {
      this.canvas.drawImage(this.loadedImg, 0, 0);
    }
  }
```

[image]